# Wildcard searching between words with CRC mode in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql, wildcard-expansion

I use sphinx with CRC mode and min_infix_length = 1 and I want to use wildcard searching between character of a keyword. Assume I have some data like these in my index files:

```
name
-------
mickel
mick
mickol
mickil
micknil
nickol
nickal
```

and when I search for all record that their's name start with 'mick' and end with 'l':

```
select * from all where match ('mick*l')
```

I expect the results should be like this:

```
name
-------
mickel
mickol
mickil
micknil
```

but nothing returned. How can I do that?

- I know that I can do this in dict=keywords mode but I should use crc mode for some reasons.
- I also used '^' and '$' operators and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use 'middle' wildcards with CRC. One of the reaons for dict=keywords, the wildcards it can support are **much** more flexible.

With CRC, it 'precomputes' all the wildcard combinations, and injects them as seperate keywords in index, eg for

eg `mickel` as a document word, and with `min_prefix_len=1`, `indexer` willl create the words:

```
mickel
mickel*
micke*
mick*
mic*
mi*
m*
```

... as words in index, so all the combinations can match. If using `min_infix_len`, it also has to do all the combinations at the start as well (so `(word_length)^2 + 1` combinations)

... if it had to precompute all the combinations for wildcards in the middle, would be a lot more again. Particularly if then allows all for middle AND start/end combinations as well)

---

Although having said that, you can rewrite

```
select * from all where match ('mick*l')
```

as

```
select * from all where match ('mick* *l')
```

because with min_infix_len, the start and end will be indexed as sperate words. Jus need to insist that both match. (although can't think how to make them bot match the same word!)

Comment: I used "NEAR/1" according to your previous answer but I don't know why it didn't work While I was expecting to work properly. Anyway, '* *' is working now.

Comment: yes, realised NEAR didnt work after posting. It must check >0, rather than just checking <=1